# CentOS 7.2 Udev rules could not automount USB storage device

Tags: linux, udev, automount

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-storage.rules
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="20060774501DE92200EA", SYMLINK+="USBDisk%n", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount /dev/USBDisk%n /mnt/"
```

When I insert USB storage device or execute the following commands it always could not be mounted:

```
udevadm trigger --action=add
```

Below is the debug information:

```
# udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1
```

[debug info](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23378037/)

I figured the mount command was invoked, but I had no idea about why mount failed.

Could anybody take a look at it ? Thanks !

Comment: You will get better answers from server fault, this question isn't really about programming

Answer (score 1):

Changed /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service item "MountFlags=slave" to "MountFlags=shared" fixed this issue.

Ref:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154318